# Alert Box is not closing

Tags: javascript

I have list of text boxes which contains Percentage values like 2.5% etc. There's one validation to check whether user has entered any special character or not. If so, alert box should pop up with proper alert message. But alert box is not closing whenever I am entering any invalid data. From Task Manager. I have to close IE. Any help will be appreciated.

**JSP Code-**

```
<html:text property="manualValPctNum" name="manualValueInputPO"  styleId="manualValPctNum" size="25"  indexed="true" maxlength="25" onblur="javascript:formatValues('moduleForm', '${row.index}')" onfocus="javascript:removeValueFormat('moduleForm', '${row.index}')"/>
```

**JavaScript Code-**

```
function formatValues(form, rowIndex){
    var beginElem = "manualValueInputPO[";
    var endElement = "]";
    var attributeName =beginElem+ rowIndex+endElement;
    formatPercentAmount(form,attributeName);
    value = "";
}

function formatPercentAmount(form, attributeName){
    var manualValueAmt = document.getElementsByName(attributeName+".manualValueAmt")[0];
    var manualValPctNum = document.getElementsByName(attributeName+".manualValPctNum")[0];
    var decimalForTabOut = document.getElementsByName(attributeName+".decimalForTabOut")[0];
    if(manualValPctNum.value != undefined && manualValPctNum.valu`enter code here`e != ''){
        if(isNaN(manualValPctNum.value)){
            alert("Enter numeric value only without entering any '$', comma, '( )', '%', or alphabets. Use '-' when entering a negative value.");
            value = "true";
            manualValPctNum.focus();
            manualValPctNumFlag = true;
            modifiedString = "";
            replacedChar = "";
        }else{
            var amt = manualValPctNum.value;
            amt = amt.toString();
            decimalForTabOut.value  = amt.indexOf('.');
            var indexPos = amt.indexOf('.');
            if(indexPos == -1){
                modifiedString = amt.concat("00");
                nonDecimalPoint = true;
            }else{
            var pctNumBeforeDecimal = amt.substring(0,indexPos);
            var pctNumAfterDecimal = amt.substring(indexPos + 1,amt.length);
            var modifiedIndexPos = indexPos + 2;
            var pctNum = pctNumBeforeDecimal.concat(pctNumAfterDecimal);
            for(var i = 0; i<pctNum.length; i++){
                if(i == modifiedIndexPos){
                    replacedChar = pctNum[i];
                    modifiedString = modifiedString.concat('.');
                    modifiedString = modifiedString.concat(replacedChar);
                }else{
                    if(modifiedString == undefined || modifiedString == ""){
                    modifiedString  = pctNum[i];
                }else{
                    modifiedString = modifiedString.concat(pctNum[i])   
                }
            }
            }
            }
            manualValueAmt.value = modifiedString+"%";
            manualValPctNum.value = modifiedString+"%";
            modifiedString = "";
            replacedChar = "";
            manualValPctNumFlag = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this an IE only issue ?

Comment: @Harsha...I have to run this code in IE only and not in other browsers.

Comment: @harsha..I tested it in Chrome, It's working fine. Alert box is closing properly.

Answer (score 0):

please change onFocus event with onClick event,
with onFocus, it will call the function whenever you click on the free space on the browser